# The value of a dynamically created <select> is not being set

Tags: javascript, dom

// first I create the select element

```
 let list;
    let sel = document.createElement('select');
    sel.style.fontSize = "18px";
    sel.style.float = "right";
    sel.style.marginTop = "12px";
    sel.style.marginRight = "10px";
    sel.id = "select" + x;
```

// next I create the options for the select element

```
    for (let y = 0; y < selectSizes.length; y++){
        list = document.createElement('option');
        list.value = Number(selectCosts[y]);
        let selectedValue = Number(list.value).toFixed(2);
        list.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Size - " + selectSizes[y] + " : $" + selectedValue));
        sel.innerHTML += list.outerHTML;
    }
```

//finally I try to get the value of the select element but it throws a null error

```
    alert(document.getElementById("select"+x).value);
    div1.appendChild(sel);
```

The value of the select element is not being set. Does anyone know why?

Comment: You haven't added the select to the DOM, therefore `document.getElementById()` isn't returning anything

Comment: `"+x)`  AND `" + x;` what is x

Comment: Also, as an aside to the problem, I would assume from the context that you're creating this in a loop given the `x` index variable used to dynamically set the `id`. Note that this is an anti-pattern. I would strongly suggest you look in to using `<template />` content instead, along with common generic classes instead of dynamically created `id`

Comment: I am with @RoryMcCrossan re: template ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template

Comment: I suggest you NOT use `.innerHTML` but instead append the child nodes and `list = document` list is undefined/not declared here

Comment: Option constructor is a nice shortcut ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement/Option

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I did not have your arrays but created some with some values then used them to create a new select.  You can use this as a pattern passing to the function where to put the select and the name/value pairs to use.

I added some slightly ugly CSS to show you can do that without code - simply use the CSS.

Notes:

- this gets the count (starts at 0) so we can use it for the id suffix since the number will be the "next" one

`const selectCount = document.querySelectorAll('select').length;`

- I used a string template literal here: re: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

  ```js
  `Size - ${selectSizes[y].name} : $${selectCosts[y]}`
  ```

```js
function createSelect(container, optionValues) {
  const selectCount = document.querySelectorAll('select').length;
  const selectList = document.createElement("select");
  selectList.id = "select-" + selectCount;
  optionValues.forEach((ov, key) => {
    selectList[key] = new Option(ov.name, ov.value);
  });
  selectList.classList.add('selector-cool');
  container.appendChild(selectList);
}

let selectSizes = [{
  name: "small",
  value: 0
}, {
  name: "medium",
  value: 0
}, {
  name: "giant",
  value: 0
}];
const selectCosts = [1.23, 9.88, 7.54];

function setupOptions(nvPairs, costs) {
  //set costs
  for (let y = 0; y < nvPairs.length; y++) {
    nvPairs[y].value = costs[y];
  }
  // setup the names
  for (let y = 0; y < nvPairs.length; y++) {
    nvPairs[y].name = `Size - ${nvPairs[y].name} : $${costs[y]}`;
  }
  return nvPairs;
}

const optList = setupOptions(selectSizes, selectCosts);
//Create and add options, append to container
const container = document.querySelector('.select-container');
createSelect(container, optList);
// do stuff with it including add a change event handler to the last one (assumes order)
const mySelect = container.querySelector('select.selector-cool:last-child');
mySelect.value = optList[1].value;

console.log(mySelect.value);
mySelect.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  console.log('NewValue:', this.value);
  console.log('ID:', this.id);
});
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.select-container {
  padding-top: 0.667em;
  padding-right: 0.555em;
}

.selector-cool {
  font-size: 1.125em;
  color: #0000FF;
  border: solid 1px #00C0FF;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  background-color: #00ff0020;
}

.selector-cool option {
  padding: 0.5em;
  font-size: 1.125em;
}

.selector-cool option:checked {
  background-color: #0000ff20;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<div class="select-container"></div>
```